# How to edit Kernel parameters

Tags: 12.10, sound, radeon, hdmi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-boot-parameter)

I'm using an Acer Aspire one 722 with Ubuntu 12.10 (32 bit).

I've been having problems with getting audio to play over HDMI and after some searching around, I found that I have edit the kernel parameter so that it reflects `radeon.audio=1`, which will enable audio over HDMI.

My problem is that I don't know how to make that fix.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to be root for the following.

you have to edit your grub config. open `/etc/default/grub` with your preferred text editor and look for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add `radeon.audio=1` to the end of it.

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

becomes

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1"

now save the file and run `update-grub`

you may also want to try to add this parameters at boot time to ensure it works before doing all of the above.
after you power on you may need to hold Shift to get the grub menu to appear after it appears press e and add `radeon.audio=1` to the end of a line similar to this

> linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-server root=UUID=11111 ro quiet splash

becomes

> linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-server root=UUID=11111 ro quiet splash radeon.audio=1

and press b to boot with the added parameter

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, audio still isn't working for some reason though.